Using arbitrary curves as the basis for a parking lot diagram
Here's what I want to do. I want to take a curve in TikZ and have some path decoration that is able to subdivide this curve into equal spaced intervals and draw a line in some direction away from the curve.
I know there's ambiguity here that would require options to specify: How many intervals? Which side of the curve? Which direction should the lines go (perpendicular to the tangent of the curve or pointed in some fixed orientation)? How long should the lines be?
Basically, imagine a birds-eye view of a parking lot. If I get the curbs of the lot drawn in TikZ I'd like to auto-populate the parking spaces along those curbs.

Have a look at section "50.6 Arbitrary Markings" of the user guide
